# How many LED pot lights shall i put on my sloped ceiling?

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting, slope

My ceiling is sloped /\ and i want to install pot lights

[These ones](https://www.amazon.ca/Ensenior-Recessed-Lighting-Junction-Brightness/dp/B08BHXMVV7/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=1I7C97H7XJM95&keywords=Recessed%2BSlim%2BPot%2BLight%2Band%2BCeiling%2BLight%2B5000k&qid=1660101260&sprefix=recessed%2Bslim%2Bpot%2Blight%2Band%2Bceiling%2Blight%2B5000k%2Caps%2C96&sr=8-1-spons&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExTzJIVUZDSUI0WjZLJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjk5MjM4WDNESUpERUZaWVhMJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA0NTgwMjQzVk9JTDM0WjhGOENEJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ&th=1) 6in, 12W, 6000K

the living room where these need to be installed is 14'0" x 16'4"

Any advice on how many I pot lights like these I can install

shall I put them all in one line (each side of the ceiling)

or 2 rows of pots on each side as illustrated here

[image]

Comment: Not all pot lights are the same - what's the beam spread angle on the ones you are considering? What's the ceiling height? (At edge and peak, I suppose, for the ceiling shown.) Consider also a series of triangles for the layout, to make things more even.

Comment: Manufactured by address in Texas, but country of origin China - that doesn't add up.  Anyway, buried somewhere in the user manual is the basic spec that's not in any of the sales listing, 120 degree beam angle. You could run a set down the peak and a set near each wall...

Comment: It really depends a lot on what you will be doing in there. For general room lighting one row centered down each side is plenty of light. If you are wanting to be able to paint pin stripes on miniature model cars at a table, that may not be enough light. Typically, one row centered down each side would be enough "general room light" to comfortably get around. Anything else you need would be done with specific "task lights" such as a desk lamp. The current thinking is to put in a bunch of lights and put them on a dimmer- I guess that is OK- seems a waste to me.

Comment: Putting this kind of ceiling lights on a sloped ceiling will make them shine "in your face"